# Setting JqueryUI datepicker on a AJAX incoming form

Tags: jquery-ui, load, datepicker, live

I'm trying to put a JqueryUI Datepicker on an AJAX appearing form.
The traditional `$(".datepicker").datepicker(datepickerParams);` does not work since the ".datepicker" element is not present on DOM ready.

I've tried the `live()` method but there is no `load` event on `<input>`.

Then, I do the following :

```
$("#datepicker_button").live('click', function() {  
    $('.multiFieldsDatepicker').datepicker(liveMultiFieldsDatepickerParams).focus();
});
```

It works when I focus on the input field but I can't put the calendar icon to show the calendar.

Is it possible to catch an event when the form appears and set the datepicker with `$(".datepicker").datepicker(datepickerParams);` ?